# Checking status of item in master-detail in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables, namely:

- Product
- ProductVariant
- SizeVariant

`Product` is the master table , `productvariant` is its child table of it and `sizevariant` is productvariant's child table.

All these tables have column of status which indicates whether they are alive or not.
I want to check that whether there are any products whose `productvariants` and `sizevariants status` is dead but the `product` itself is alive.

Comment: do you really need to check the sizevariants for the product?  it seems like you would want to check productvariant for product, and then check sizevariant for productvariant

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from product p
where p.status = 'alive' 
  and not exists (select 1 
                  from   productvariant 
                  where  productid = p.id 
                    and  status='alive')
```

should get you all products that don't have an 'alive' variant.  following the same formula, you could also check for product variants without any 'alive' size variants:

```
select *
from productvariant pv
where p.status = 'alive'  
  not exists (select 1 
              from   sizevariant 
              where  productvariantid = pv.id 
                and  status='alive')
```

Comment: the query shows me all of the products who are dead, but I only want those whose children are dead and they them self are not. I am trying to make a cursor to achieve this task.

Comment: @kaibuki, i've updated to limit the returned set to have only those where the product is 'alive'.  i can't see why you'd use a cursor for this task.

Comment: @kaibuki: Is `status <> 'alive'` the same thing as `status ='dead'`?

Comment: Consider an 'alive' product that has no variants: your first query will select it but can it really be said that is is in the set "products whose productvariants and sizevariants status is dead"?

Comment: these semantics games are tiresome.  if my post helps anyone, great.

Answer (score 1):

> whether there are any products whose
>   `productvariants` and `sizevariants`
>   status is dead but the product itself
>   is alive

```
SELECT P1.product_ID
  FROM Products AS P1
INTERSECT
SELECT V1.product_ID
  FROM productvariants AS V1        
 WHERE V1.status = 'Dead'
INTERSECT 
SELECT V1.product_ID
  FROM productvariants AS V1        
       INNER JOIN sizevariants AS S1
         ON V1.product_variant_ID = S1.product_variant_ID
 WHERE S1.status = 'Dead';
```

Alternatively (warning: may look unnecessarily complex):

```
SELECT P1.product_ID
  FROM Products AS P1
 WHERE P1.status = 'Alive'
       AND EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM productvariants AS V1        
                    WHERE P1.product_ID = V1.product_ID            
                          AND V1.status = 'Dead'
                  )
       AND EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                     FROM sizevariants AS S1
                          INNER JOIN productvariants AS V1
                             ON V1.product_variant_ID = S1.product_variant_ID
                    WHERE P1.product_ID = V1.product_ID            
                          AND S1.status = 'Dead'
                  );
```

Comment: you've got some alias issues in your subqueries, and, i'll reiterate, i did not ask this question, the original poster was @kaibuki.  you seem pretty aggressive about it though... :)

Comment: also, the first one seems unnecessarily complex.  you should be able to accomplish that with 2 inner joins, and no correlated subqueries

Comment: @nathan gonzalez: "complex" is in the eye of the beholder ;) I find the subqueries easy on the eye. I agree, there is more than one way to skin a cat... but you'd need *three* inner joins for them to be semantically the same, methinks.